# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{.UpdateProfileFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragmentactivity

I'm having this error after clicking button in my AccountFragment

```
public class AccountFragment extends Fragment  {
    private static final String TAG = "Profile" ;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    FirebaseUser currentUser;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    TextView tv_name, tv_email, tv_gender, tv_home, tv_phone;
    private String userID;
    Button btn_update;



    public AccountFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, container, false);

        tv_name=view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        tv_email=view.findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
        tv_gender=view.findViewById(R.id.tv_gender);
        tv_home=view.findViewById(R.id.tv_home);
        tv_phone=view.findViewById(R.id.tv_phone);
        btn_update=view.findViewById(R.id.btn_update);


        //ini
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        userID = currentUser.getUid();
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Customer").child(firebaseAuth.getUid());

        //For Retrieve Information
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {


            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.d( TAG, "onDataChange :" +dataSnapshot);

                    Customer cust = dataSnapshot.getValue(Customer.class);
                    tv_name.setText(cust.getName());
                    tv_email.setText(cust.getEmail());
                    tv_gender.setText(cust.getGender());
                    tv_home.setText(cust.getHome_address());
                    tv_phone.setText(cust.getTelephone_number());

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        //For Update Method

        btn_update.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openUpdateProfile();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    // For update and pass information method
    private void openUpdateProfile() {


        Intent intent= new Intent(getActivity(), UpdateProfileFragment.class);

        //pass value from current to next page
        intent.putExtra("name",tv_name.getText().toString().trim());
        intent.putExtra("email", tv_email.getText().toString().trim());
        intent.putExtra("Home Address",tv_home.getText().toString().trim());
        intent.putExtra("Telephone", tv_phone.getText().toString().trim());
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

after clicking the button i got this error
2019-09-22 22:20:32.757 6631-6631/com.example.g E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.g, PID: 6631
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.g/com.example.g.UpdateProfileFragment}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.g.UpdateProfileFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2843)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.gerobokgo.UpdateProfileFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:69)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:41)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1215)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2831)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

UpdateProfileFragment

```
public class UpdateProfileFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    EditText tv_name, tv_email, tv_home, tv_phone;
    Button btn_update;

    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    FirebaseUser currentUser;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;


    public UpdateProfileFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_update_profile, container, false);


        //get data from intert (data from previous page)

        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        String name = intent.getStringExtra("Name");
        String email = intent.getStringExtra("Email");
        String address = intent.getStringExtra(" Shipping Address");
        String phone = intent.getStringExtra("Telephone Number");

        //ini
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Customer").child(firebaseAuth.getUid());

        tv_name = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        tv_email = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
        tv_home = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_home);
        tv_phone = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_phone);

        tv_name.setText(name);
        tv_email.setText(email);
        tv_home.setText(address);
        tv_phone.setText(phone);

        btn_update.setOnClickListener(this);


        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }

    private void updateProfile() {
        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();

        String userUid = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        String name = tv_name.getText().toString().trim();
        String email = tv_email.getText().toString().trim();
        String home = tv_home.getText().toString().trim();
        String phone = tv_phone.getText().toString().trim();

        Customer cust = new Customer(userUid, name, email, home, phone);
        databaseReference.child("Customer").child(userUid).setValue(cust).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Update Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    getActivity().finish();
                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), AccountFragment.class));


                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't open fragment using startActivity, you need to implement a callback which triggers when your user's profile has updated successfully. In your host activity make an interface as follows :

```
public interface UpdateProfileSuccess{
    void presentAccountFragment();
}
```

Also instantiate that in activity as:

```
UpdateProfileSuccess callback = new UpdateProfileSuccess(){
@Override
void presentAccountFragment(){
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new 
        AccuontFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

In your update profile fragment make a constructor taking that callback as :

```
private MainActivity.UpdateProfileSuccess callback;
public UpdateProfileFragment(MainActivity.UpdateProfileSuccess callback){
    this.callback = callback;
}
```

Finally in onComplete of your request consume that callback as:

```
callback.presentAccountFragment();
```

This way your activity will be responsible of presenting AccountFragment.

Comment: Do I have to delete the startActivity? and what should i replace the startActivity coding with?

Comment: Yes you will have to delete that startActivity line and use callback.presentAccountFragment(); there.

Comment: @lilin If you get this code working, please accept and upvote :)

Comment: would you like to look at my AccountFragment?

Comment: Sure. Also post your activity's code where you are opening AccountFragment

Comment: @lilin same thing, use this callback in both fragments to move A -> B and B -> A.
Add another abstract method in interface, and use that in account fragment as its used in update profile fragment. Make sure to update your instance in activity so that it also provides implementation of the new method you are going to create.